# Simple code for calculating damage increase

Tags: c#, game, unity3d

In my little game project, I have the following piece of code, in the static class `DamageHelper`, that takes a `Spell`, and returns it's damage in the `Entity`:

```
public static float DamageIncrease(SpellData attack, Entity caster)
{
    //Elemental damage is more increased by wisdom attribute
    //Impact damage is more increased by dominance attribute 
    //summon level is increased by control attribute

    float bonus = 0f;
    switch (attack.element)
    {
        case Element.Fire:
        case Element.Earth:
        case Element.Water:
        case Element.Wind:
            bonus = caster.wisdom * 0.3f + caster.dominance * 0.1f + caster.control * 0.1f;
            break;
        case Element.Impact:
            bonus = caster.wisdom * 0.1f + caster.dominance * 0.3f + caster.control * 0.1f;
            break;
        default:
            bonus = caster.wisdom * 0.1f + caster.dominance * 0.1f + caster.control * 0.3f;
            break;
    }

    return attack.damage + bonus;
}
```

The function above is called by the this `RealDamage` function, that may also be improved:

```
public static float RealDamage(SpellData attack, Entity target, Entity caster)
    {
        float max_variation = attack.damage_variation / 2f;
        float min_variation = max_variation - attack.damage_variation;
        float resist_percent = 0f;
        float dmg = DamageIncrease(attack, caster) + Random.Range(min_variation, max_variation);
        switch (attack.element)
        {
            case (Element.Fire):
                resist_percent = target.GetFireResistance();
                break;
            case (Element.Earth):
                resist_percent = target.GetEarthResistance();
                break;
            case (Element.Water):
                resist_percent = target.GetWaterResistance();
                break;
            case (Element.Wind):
                resist_percent = target.GetWindResistance();
                break;
            case (Element.Impact):
                resist_percent = target.GetPhysicalResistance();
                break;
        }

        dmg -= (dmg * resist_percent / 100f);

        if (dmg < 1f)
            dmg = 0f;

        return dmg;
    }
```

and this one is called when player casts a spell:

```
float damage = DamageHelper.RealDamage(data, e, spellCaster);
dmg.GetComponent<DamageText>().MakeTooltip(data.element, damage, e.transform.position);
e.TakeDamage(damage);
```

It's pretty simple, but I would like to know if there are any ways it can be improved. Also, I will probably add more formulas, since I have to get the bonus from the `Entity` equipment. In this case, where should I put these?

Comment: I am not sure that helper class should contain game logic ...

Comment: Helper is just the name, maybe it was a bad choice D: because it was intended to contain all the formulas to calculate damage

Comment: @ArturoTemplário can you show how you cast spells?

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy sure, one second

Comment: *" was intended to contain all the formulas to calculate damage"*. So, `DamageCalculator` then?

Comment: @radarbob yes, that is a good name!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define some data structures.

- Data definitions are clear, complete, obvious, in one place
- DRY principle - a single place to change data values
- client code does not change if data values change
- Declared "Default" Element to keep code consistent
- Reusable

.

```
public DamageFactor {
   public float Wisdom    { get; protected set; }
   public float Domanince { get; protected set; }
   public float Control   { get; protected set; }

   public DamageFactor (int wisdom, int domanince, int control) { ... }
}

public Dictionary<Element, DamageFactor> Damage = new Dictionary<Element, DamageFactor>() {  
    { Element.Fire,    new DamageFactor { Wisdom = 0.3f, Dominance = 0.1f, Control = 0.1f },
    { Element.Earth,   new DamageFactor { Wisdom = 0.3f, Dominance = 0.1f, Control = 0.1f },
    { Element.Wind,    new DamageFactor { Wisdom = 0.3f, Dominance = 0.1f, Control = 0.1f },
    { Element.Water,   new DamageFactor { Wisdom = 0.3f, Dominance = 0.1f, Control = 0.1f },
    { Element.Impact,  new DamageFactor { Wisdom = 0.1f, Dominance = 0.3f, Control = 0.1f },
    { Element.Default, new DamageFactor { Wisdom = 0.1f, Dominance = 0.1f, Control = 0.3f }
};

public Dictionary<Element, int> Resistance = new Dictionary<Element, int>() {
    { Element.Fire, 12 },
    { Element.Earth, 9 },
    { Element.Water, 7 },
    { Element.Wind, 5 }, 
    { Element.Impact, 3 },
    { Element.Default, 1 }
};

public static float DamageIncrease(SpellData attack, Entity caster) {
//Elemental damage is more increased by wisdom attribute
//Impact damage is more increased by dominance attribute 
//summon level is increased by control attribute

float bonus = 0f;
bonus = caster.wisdom    * Damage[attack.element].Wisdom +
        caster.dominance * Damage[attack.element].Dominance +
        caster.control   * Damage[attach.element].Control;

return attack.damage + bonus;
}

public static float RealDamage(SpellData attack, Entity target, Entity caster) {
    float max_variation = attack.damage_variation / 2f;
    float min_variation = max_variation - attack.damage_variation;
    float resist_percent = 0f;
    float dmg = DamageIncrease(attack, caster) + Random.Range(min_variation, max_variation);

    resist_percent = Resistance[attack.element];
    dmg -= (dmg * resist_percent / 100f);

    if (dmg < 1f)
        dmg = 0f;

    return dmg;
}
```

Comment: The `resist_percent` is a property of the Entity (`target`), based on the attack element.  A static dictionary won't work.

Comment: This actually helped me, mainly the `Dictionary<Element, int>` part, thank you!